# Use Ajax to call a ColdFusion script on a different server (same network)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have the following in a ColdFusion page that pulls in some data for us once the page has loaded:

```
ajaxRequest#RowURnumber[I]#.open("POST", "/cfapps/include/scriptname.cfm?i=#RowNumber[I]#", true);
ajaxRequest#RowURnumber[I]#.send(null);
```

Would it be possible to host this script on a different server in our network and call it with the above code? I have tried using a http address and a UNC path but they don't seem to work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply use ajax to access any page other than the same domain even its the same network.

For your solution, you would use a proxy page in your domain,
From the front end you would perform an AJAX request to this proxy page in your domain,
which will fetch the contents from that coldfusion page and pass it through to frontend.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url :'url to a proxy page in server A',
  success: function (){//...}
});
```

In server A you will have a proxy page say proxy.cfm

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.serverB.com/the actual page..." />
<cfset html = cfhttp.FileContent />
<cfoutput>#html#</cfoutput>
```

So your AJAX will ask Server A to get the contents from server B and return it.

Comment: Hi Broncha, thanks for your reply. Would it be possible for you to elaborate on exactly how this scenario would hang together?

Comment: what is your back end written in?

Comment: ColdFusion. I'm trying to call a ColdFusion script on "server A" from a ColdFusion page on "server B" using Ajax.

Comment: check my updated answer.. I dont know much about coldfusion, but that the mechanism you need to implement

Answer (score 1):

If the script is located at a different domain then the same-origin policy of the browser will prevent the script from running.  There are some ways around this (JSONP, CORS) that you can look into. JSONP will be the more backward-compatible solution.